# enable switch user list for admin

Tags: drupal-7, admin

I want to login as other user for development purpose in drupal I want to list switch user for admin login.I have enabled devel module still list not shown in admin login. How to show the switch user list in admin loggin page

Answer (score 0):

There's [Masquerade](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade).

The Masquerade module allows site administrators (or anyone with enough permissions) to switch users and surf the site as that user (no password required). That person can switch back to their own user account at any time.

Another module which accomplishes something similar is [Role Switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/roleswitcher).